# GoogleCharts: Is it not possible to create a calendar within a ChartWrapper?

Tags: calendar, google-visualization

I have been trying for a while to get a Calendar to render as part of a Google Charts dashboard, using

```
[...]
var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Calendar', //also tried "calendar"/"Calendar"/"CalendarChart"
[...]
```

Should this be possible at all, or can calendars not be created with ChartWrappers for some reason?

The calendar is being built just fine with exactly tghe same set of data and options if I create it as an individual chart based on [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#SimpleExample).

Comment: Using `'Calendar'` should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/275m9/

Comment: I was trying this, and it doesn't work when following the [Dashboard example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#using_controls_and_dashboards): http://jsfiddle.net/KLY97/ What struck me is that you are loading the calendar package in your example, whereas per the documentation, "A dashboard requires only two libraries to be included or loaded on the page: the Google AJAX API and the Google Visualization controls package"; which is what I was attempting. Do you see a way of making a calendar work within a dashboard?

Comment: Ahh, yes, looks like that is a bug.  I suspect that the ChartWrapper doesn't know where to find the Calendar package, so it isn't getting loaded.  If you include the package in the load call alongside the controls package, it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/KLY97/1/ (note that I also had to change column id's to labels in the DataTable in order for the RangeFilter's `filterColumnLabel` option to work).